# Maven structure for automated UI test

Tags: java, maven-2, selenium

I have got to know that src/test/java is used for writing unit tests.
I was wondering if I should use same location for automated UI tests I write in Selenium.
And if so then should I be following structure as -

```
src/test/java

  com.mycompany.pageobjects - contains application page objects
  com.mycompany.uielements - contains UI elements of application
  com.mycompany.tests - contains selenium tests of application
  <some more packages>

src/test/resources - contains test data i.e. plain text, xml or properties files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same structure for UI Test via Selenium, but i would recommend them to name like XXXXIT.java for Integration Test which is executed by the Maven-Failsafe-Plugin in relationship with Selenium.

Furthermore i would recommend to have a separate module which contains the UI Integration Tests. This makes life easier. Take a look [here](http://khmarbaise.github.com/maui/it-example-container.html).